# GetAttr Function Problems (Python 3)

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.x, setattr

I have the following in a Python script:

```
setattr(stringRESULTS, "b", b)
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Can any-one telling me what the problem is here?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear... what's your problem?

Comment: I want to make dynamic variables that work like this:

(string contained in variable STRINGRESULTS).b = (string contained in variable b)

Which I'm told I can use with setattr: [link](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#setattr)

But doing what I think it tells me to do in the Python doc results in that error.

Comment: @EdenCrow: just to be clear, are you attempting to add an attribute called "b" to the stringRESULTS object, or are you attempting to add an attribute called b to an object *named by* the contents of stringRESULTS, so that if stringRESULTS was the string "fred", and b was 7, you'd want it to dynamically do the equivalent of "fred.b = 7"?

Comment: The second one (where fred.b = 7 in your example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this.  To quote the inestimable [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056007/487339),

> "If you ever find yourself using quoted names to refer to variables,
>   there's usually a better way to do whatever you're trying to do."

[Here you're one level up and using a string variable for the name, but it's the same underlying issue.]  Or as S. Lott followed up with in the same thread:

> "90% of the time, you should be using a dictionary. The other 10% of
>   the time, you need to stop what you're doing entirely."

If you're using the contents of stringRESULTS as a pointer to some object `fred` which you want to `setattr`, then these objects you want to target must already exist somewhere, and [a dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is the natural data structure to store them.  In fact, depending on your use case, you might be able to use dictionary key/value pairs instead of attributes in the first place.

IOW, my version of what (I'm guessing) you're trying to do would probably look like

```
d[stringRESULTS].b = b
```

or

```
d[stringRESULTS]["b"] = b
```

depending on whether I wanted/needed to work with an object instance or a dictionary would suffice.

(P.S. relatively few people subscribe to the python-3.x tag.  You'll usually get more attention by adding the bare 'python' tag as well.)

Comment: Re: tags - use `python-X` tag for when your problem is specific to version X of python. If it's general, use `python` as DSM suggests.

Comment: OK. I will have a look into using dictionaries and using the python tag in future questions - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since **str** is a low-level primitive type, you can't really set any arbitrary attribute on it. You probably need either a **dict** or a subclass of **str**:

```
class StringResult(str):
    pass
```

which should behave as you expect:

```
my_string_result = StringResult("spam_and_eggs")
my_string_result.b = b
```

EDIT:

If you're trying to do what *DSM* suggests, ie. modify a property on a variable that has the same name as the value of the `stringRESULTS` variable then this should do the trick:

```
locals()[stringRESULTS].b = b
```

**Please note that this is an extremely dangerous operation and can wreak all kinds of havoc on your app if you aren't careful.**